# If a line integral is 0, does the function have to be conservative?

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

If a line integral is 0, does the function have to be conservative?

Take the line integral $\oint_{C}^{}y^4dx+2xy^3dy$, which is equal to 0 over the bounded region C: $x^2+2y^2=2$. However, I was under the impression that if a line integral equaled 0, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ would be true based on Clairaut's theorem. However, P and Q in this line integral, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=4y^3$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=2y^3$, which aren't equal but are instead scalar multiples of each other.

Is this function $\vec F(x,y)=P\hat{\imath}+Q\hat{\jmath}$ conservative, or am I missing something?

Comment: What is the curve? $x^2+2y^2 = ?$

Comment: In general the vector field $F$ will be conservative if the line integral is $0$ around every simple closed curve. It isn't enough that it is $0$ on some curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a vector field is conservative in a given domain then its line integral over *every* closed curve in that domain is zero. Just because the line integral is zero for the given curve does not necessarily mean that it is zero for every closed curve. For example, is it zero over a unit square with vertices at $(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)$ and $(0, 1)$?

In general note that the integral of an odd function is zero if the region has symmetry about $x$ or $y$ axis. In this specific case, assuming $C$ is $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$ then parametrizing as $r(t) = (\cos t, \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \sin t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ and $r'(t) = (- \sin t, \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \cos t)$.

So, $ \vec F \cdot r'(t) = -\dfrac{\sin^5t}{4} + \dfrac{\cos^2 t \sin^3 t}{2}  = \dfrac{\sin^3 t}{2} - \dfrac{3 \sin^5 t}{4}$.

Integral of odd power of $\sin$ function over $(0, 2\pi)$ is always zero.

Answer (score 1):

To be conservative the integral over EVERY piecewise $C^1$ closed loop must vanish. It is possible that for some particular loop the line integral is zero, but not for all of them. Recall that conservative implies that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$.

But you just showed that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\neq\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$, hence the vector field is not conservative (this is just a rephrasing of my previous sentence in the contrapositive form).